# My audio devices gradually disappearing

Tags: audio, windows-11, microphone, input-device, audio-output

I am just using my computer normally a few days ago and just finished a Zoom call with no issue. But a few hours later, I found my computer telling me it can't find my microphone ("no microphone installed") when I am trying to use Window's screen-recording software, I tried giving all software access to my microphone, but it is not working. Then today, after a strange computer freeze (a sudden glitching of my Windows taskbar, and then my computer just froze up), I forced restarted my computer and found it telling me "no audio device installed". And I can't find any audio device in my "device manager" either.
[image]

I am using an HP Laptop Model 15-dy2013ca that already have built-in microphone and speaker. I just bought it last year.

EDIT: I have enabled "show hidden driver" and this is what is showing up:
[image]

But my audio system is still not working though

Comment: I would say it's a driver issue (where Windows updates to a bad driver, seen this with AMD graphic cards) but b/c you aren't seeing the hardware in 'Device Manager' my guess would be a hardware issue.

You could test this out by trying a Linux Live CD and is if happens again.

Or try opening and closing the laptop a few times, could be the wire for the mic is getting pinched in the hinge area.

Comment: Enable the viewing of hidden devices and update your question

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, this could be the result of a bad Windows update on your version of Windows, you can try rolling back recently deployed Windows updates.

Also, I would test the microphone, by plugging it to other device. If that is not possible, I recommend downloading the Windows Scrubbing Tool or the troubleshooter from the [Microsoft Site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d) and uninstalling the drivers for the microphone completely and reinstall again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).